# Definition of Zero-truncated Poisson distribution

Tags: poisson-distribution, conditional-probability, truncation

The definition of zero-truncated Poisson (ZTP) distribution is:

\begin{align}
g(k;\lambda)= P(X = k | X > 0) &= \frac{f(k;\lambda)}{1-f(0;\lambda)}  \\[8pt]
                               &= \frac{\lambda^ke^{-k}}{k!(1-e^{-\lambda})}  \\[8pt]
                               &= \frac{\lambda^k}{(e^\lambda - 1)k!}
\end{align}

The definition of conditional probability is: 
$$
P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}
$$

Now, $A = f(k;\lambda)$ and $B = 1-f(0;\lambda)$, but how is $A\cap B = f(k;\lambda)$?

Source: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-truncated_Poisson_distribution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that A(k) refers to $X=k$, B refers to $X>0$.

So - for all $k>0$ is A(k) is true B is true as well meaning:
$ \forall k>0:P(A(k)\cap B) = P(A(k)), P(A(0)\cap B)=0$

Now I see that I can stop here, but I already wrote it so...

So , what you got is $$P(A(k)|B)=\frac{p(A(k))}{P(B)}=\frac{\lambda^k}{(1-P(X=0)) k!}=\frac{\lambda^k}{(1-e^\lambda)k!}=\frac{\lambda^ke^{-\lambda}}{(1-e^{-\lambda})k!}$$

which is actually the real distribution

Comment: Could you explain how you get across that last equality (i.e. what you did to get from the LHS to the RHS of it?)